# Android: How to swipe to dismiss whole layout?

Tags: android, swipe, dismiss

I have displayed custom layout (SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) above all other views. I'm able to move with the custom layout using onTouch Event.

I would like to add simple swipe to dismiss functionality on the X- axis. How can I do it in the right way, please? I tried to use same prepared libraries but seems that these libraries are designed for use in the listviews.

I need only swipe in the x-axis to remove given layout.

Many thanks for any advice.

I tried to do following, i am able to move in the x-axis:

```
   mParentLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    Logger.d("onTouch");
                    switch (event.getAction()) {

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                            dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                            dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            view.animate()
                                    .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                                    .setDuration(0)
                                    .start();
                            Logger.d(view.getX());
                            Logger.d(view.getRight());
                            Logger.d(view.getLeft());

                            break;
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you encounter any problems in doing so? What is wrong with the methods used in those libraries to dismiss stuff of listviews?

Answer (score 2):

I created a custom View for this very purpose, so if anyone's still looking I posted a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/darnmason/38a1a5178a06470202784050f4dc1cdf)

[ViewDragHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper.html) is what you need